# Software that constantly monitors which processes write and read on disk

Tags: windows, monitoring, hard-disk

I know Windows has Performance Monitor and Resource Monitor but they don't quite check all the things on my list.

I want something like what you can see here with Process Hacker. Resource Monitor doesn't show the total bytes written and read.  And with Performance Monitor, you can only see the information after you've stopped the collector.

[image]

But another thing I need is something that saves its data to some sort of database so I can go back and see data from a specific time period. Something like what this internet monitoring tool called NetLimiter can do.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provides [Windows Performance Toolkit (WPT)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/) consisting of [Windows Performance Recorder (WPR)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/windows-performance-recorder) and [Windows Performance Analyzer (WPA)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/windows-performance-analyzer). All that again is part of the [WADK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install) and that's where you download it. Wow, what a journey!

WPT is free (gratis) for download.

During installation, deselect everything except WPT. It'll take ~620 MB on disk.

[image: Installing WPT only]

There are many options. I seldom use disk analysis, but it is available in 2 forms: Disk IO and File IO. Check if it's sufficient to record to RAM to avoid additional disk IO if that's what you want to analyze.

[image: Performance Recorder Disk Analysis]

After recording, you can analyze the results in WPA where you can select a time range and similar:

[image: Disk IO in WPA]

I can't go into details. The tool is not super easy to use, but ok once you got into it.